# Align 2 tables titles using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to align these 2 table names on top, like each table name is on top and in the middle of the table

[image]

CSS:

```
     p{
            color: blue;
        }

        table.table1 {
            float: left;
            display: inline-block
            font-size: large;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
```

HTML:

```
        <p>Employee Table</p>
        <!-- TABLE CONSTRUCTION -->
        <table class="table1">
```

Answer (score 1):

Put some wrappers around your table which do the alignment:
https://jsfiddle.net/wf5qargj/

```
<h1>Main Heading</h1>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h2>Heading T1</h2>
    <table id="t1">
      <tr><td>...<td></tr>
      ....
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h2>Heading T2</h2>
    <table id="t2">
      <tr><td>...<td></tr>
      ....
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.outer {
  display: flex;
}
td,th {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
table {
  width:300px;
}
h2 {
  text-align:center;
}
```